# PHP imap via proxy

Tags: php, proxy, imap

Is there any solution to working imap via proxy on php ? Will be great if I can use fsockopen and work with imap via proxy. How to connect to imap via proxy? How to log in, send commands ? I have looked all web and did not found any solution. There really absent enough information for this topic. Great thank in advance for anybody who can help!

Comment: The PHP built in IMAP library does not seem to support proxies, but you can always roll your own.  The description of IMAP is RFC 3501.

Comment: How I can roll my own ? Using what ? Fsockopen to proxy and using command to imap server ?

Comment: It's all socket programming.  The IMAP protocol is documented, and I'm sure there are tonnes of resources on how to send data through a socket.  However, all of IMAP, MIME, and email parsing is a very large undertaking and requires a lot of knowledge.

Answer (score 2):

```
$ch = curl_init("imaps://imap.server.com:993/INBOX;UID=1");

curl_setopt_array($ch,[
    CURLOPT_HEADER => false,
    CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,
    CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION => true,
    CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER => false,
    CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST => false,
    CURLOPT_USERNAME => 'postbox@server.com',
    CURLOPT_PASSWORD => 'password',
    CURLOPT_PROXYTYPE => CURLPROXY_SOCKS5,
    CURLOPT_PROXY => "proxy-ip-addr:proxy-port"
]);

$content = curl_exec( $ch );
curl_close($ch);
echo $content;
```

This is example how to get message #1 form Inbox.
Non-GET IMAP commands can be sent with CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST option.
For example, to delete message:

```
$ch = curl_init("imaps://imap.server.com:993/INBOX;UID=1");

curl_setopt_array($ch,[
    CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST => 'DELETE',
    CURLOPT_HEADER => false,
    CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,
    CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION => true,
    CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER => false,
    CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST => false,
    CURLOPT_USERNAME => 'postbox@server.com',
    CURLOPT_PASSWORD => 'password',
    CURLOPT_PROXYTYPE => CURLPROXY_SOCKS5,
    CURLOPT_PROXY => "proxy-ip-addr:proxy-port"
]);

$content = curl_exec( $ch );
curl_close($ch);
```

Comment: Can you please provide some explanation for this code?

Comment: Sorry, I can't imagine what needs to be clarified in this code. All at the level of basic knowledge of php.
IMAP commands for each specific task can be found in the IMAP specification. Here is described a simple, but apparently unobvious way to work with the IMAP server.